# Accessing Elasticsearch through JAVA API with Eclipse

Tags: maven, elasticsearch

I'm a beginner trying to access **elasticsearch** through JAVA with eclipse, but after following the instructions available at [this guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/_maven_repository.html) , **eclipse is not able to import packages** like `org.elasticsearch.node.*` and I haven't been able to continue.

This is my first time with Maven, and the configurations might be wrong.

This is my **pom.xml** file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>

      <name>elasticsearch</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      </properties>

      <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>${es.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </project>
```

I can access elasticsearch through a terminal or browser, but not with eclipse.  What step I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined `es.version` in your `properties` section. `mvn install` should have thrown errors because it can't download **elasticsearch** dependencies. I think [following change to your pom](https://github.com/iPrayag/spring-rest-server/blob/master/pom.xml#L13) would work.

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <es.version>0.90.3</es.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I just changed to version 1.0.0 because I'm using that.

Comment: Great. Have fun with es 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pom.xml in my eclipse Maven project. It works. Just for you reference.

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>elastic.mapper</groupId>
      <artifactId>importer</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>

      <name>importer</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      </properties>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
      </dependencies>

    </project>
```